# Is there a solution to compare a specific field in a SQL full-text search?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, full-text-search

This is my regular code and it works fine:

```
$sql = 'SELECT '
    . '* '
  . 'FROM '
    . 'item '
  . 'WHERE MATCH '
    . '(title) '
  . 'AGAINST '
    . '(:search IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) '
  . 'OR MATCH '
    . '(description) '
  . 'AGAINST '
    . '(:search IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) '
  . 'ORDER BY '
    . 'id ASC';
```

I want to compare the field "status" to the string "public" because I need only the "public" entrys, I tried something like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT '
    . '* '
  . 'FROM '
    . 'item '
  . 'WHERE MATCH '
    . '(title) '
  . 'AGAINST '
    . '(:search IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) '
  . 'OR MATCH '
    . '(description) '
  . 'AGAINST '
    . '(:search IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) '
  . 'WHERE '
    . 'status = "public" '
  . 'ORDER BY '
    . 'id ASC';
```

But with the last "WHERE" the result is nothing I expected.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added 2 WHERE statements, thats not allowed and when you use OR it is best to place brackets round the OR condition to ensure the correct result

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM item 
        WHERE status = "public"
        AND (
                MATCH (title) AGAINST (:search IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
             OR MATCH (description) AGAINST (:search IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
            )
        ORDER BY id ASC';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of errors in your query,

1. `WHERE` clause is added twice
2. Conditions in `OR` should be enclosed in round brackets '()'

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM item
   WHERE ( 
           MATCH (title) AGAINST (:search IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
           OR MATCH (description) AGAINST (:search IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
   )
   AND status = "public"
   ORDER BY
   id ASC
   ```

Also, using `SELECT *` is harmful. You can read the details about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)